# How can you test if a function is bounded by another?

Tags: functions, computational-complexity

I am trying to learn about complexity theory, which states that $f(n)$ is in $O(g)$ if, for some $C > 0$, $f(n) \leq C\cdot g(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. That's well and good; it makes sense to me, but when it comes to the exercises, I don't know how to actually prove that a given function is bounded by another! Here is an example:

$$f(n) = 5n^2 + 3n + 7\quad\mathrm{and}\quad g(n) = n^3$$

My intuition tells me that $f(n)$ is in $O(g)$ because the highest exponent in the function $f$ is smaller than in $g$; however, after plotting the two functions, it becomes clear that the constant added to $f$, $7$, prevents $g(n)$ from being greater for $g(n) < 1$. What is the "correct" way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Formally you have to prove that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}< \infty$$ In practice this is obvious since in many cases this $\limsup$ is an actual limit, and it is $0$.

Comment: @Crostul's answer is more general, but for this, it suffices to recognize $1 < n < n^2 < n^3$ for natural $n$, so that $5n^2 +3n + 7 < 5n^3 + 3n^3 + 7n^3 = 15n^3$, giving us $C = 15$.

Comment: Also, the inequality does not need to hold for all $n$. It needs to hold as $n \to \infty$ -- that is, it must hold for all $n > n_0$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we only care about natural numbers, try the first few:

$f(1)=15, g(1)=1$, so if this works, $C \geq 15$.

$f(2)=33, g(2)=8$. $15$, works here.  Now that we have a $C$ that should work, we want to check the  $Cg(n)=15n^3 \geq f(n)$ for $n=1,2,...$.

$f(n) \leq 5n^2+3n^2+7n^2=15n^2 \leq 15g(n)=15n^3$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I notice that both you and Nitin use $n \geq 1$. I didn't consider that $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$. It would be helpful if the author had used notation to indicate that...

Comment: The result is not true for $n=0$, so I assumed that $n$ starts at 1.